# Jooq is adjusting timestamptz to instant conversion using JVM timezone

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc, jooq

I have a book record in my postgres database, with the *displayTimestamp* (of type *TIMESTAMPTZ*) set to *2020-04-01T15:19:35.511599Z*. The database timezone is set to UTC.

When I query with jooq (*TIMESTAMPTZ* converted to *java.time.Instant*), such as:

```
 jooq.select(Books.BOOKS.DISPLAY_TIMESTAMP)
        .from(Books.BOOKS)
        .fetchOne()
```

I get the correct value, *2020-04-01T15:19:35.511599Z*.

However, when I query using the jooq **trunc** method:

```
 jooq.select(trunc(Books.BOOKS.DISPLAY_TIMESTAMP))
        .from(Books.BOOKS)
        .fetchOne()
```

I get the result of *2020-03-31T22:00:00Z*. The timestamp seems to be -2 hours from the expected value. I notice that when I set the JVM timezone explicitly via *-Duser.timezone=UTC*, the problem is fixed.

This shows that JOOQ is making an adjustment to the timestamp based on the JVM's timezone, but weirdly only when using the **trunc** method.

Can anybody offer any input on fixing this? Ideally I would like JOOQ (*3.13.0*) to not make any adjustment based on the JVM timezone.